# How to work with $\nabla^i$ easily like $\nabla_i$?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

It is straightforward for me to work with $\nabla_i$: like taking covariant derivative, contracting, etc. But when I want to do the same with $\nabla^i$ it is strange for me to work with, and it is more stranger when I want to contract it, e.g. $\nabla^i f\nabla_if$. This doesn't mean that I can't calculate it.

> How to work with $\nabla^i$ easily like $\nabla_i$?

The most misleading point for me is: $G^{ij}G_{jk}=G^i_k$ and $G^iG_i=tr G$ but what about $\nabla^i\nabla_i f$ or $\nabla^i\nabla_i X$ and $\nabla^i f\nabla_i f$ or $\nabla^i X\nabla_i X$?

Comment: By $\nabla^i$ do you mean the total covariant derivative with the first index raised, i.e. $\nabla^i=g^{ij}\nabla_j$?

Comment: Do you mean $\nabla^i$? What else could it be?

Comment: I think it would be useful if you tell why it is strange to work with for you, may be with a couple of examples. After reading your question I don't quite know what the problem is.

Comment: because I should convert it to $\nabla_i$ to work with, finally raising $i$ index. I want to compute it directly (maybe) like experts.

Comment: Do you want formulas? I don't think anyone bothers to memorize formulas for working with $\nabla^i$. At least I replace it with $g^{ij}\nabla_j$ every time I see it and haven't had a problem, but again I may be misunderstanding what you mean. That's why I think it would be good to have an example of what you want to achieve.

Comment: What's $G$? ${}{}$

Comment: Any tensor that my expressions make sense.

Comment: [Related answer!](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2575739/272127)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The confusion **might** comes from the following claim

$$ G^{ij} G_{jk} = {G^i}_k, \ \ \ G^i G_i = \operatorname {tr}G, $$

since both are false (or at least I have never seen anyone used this).

Let $g = (g_{ij})$ be the metric tensor. Then for any two tensor $G_{ij}$, ${G^i}_j$ is by definition

$$ {G^i}_j = g^{ik}G_{kj},$$

which is completely different from $G^{ik} G_{kj}$, which $G^{ij}$ by definition is

$$ G^{ij} = g^{ik} g^{jl} G_{kl}.$$

On the other hand, if you have a tensor $G = G_i$, then one cannot take trace of $G$. In general, if $A = {A^i}_{j}$ is a $(1, 1)$-tensor, then $\operatorname {tr} A$ is a scalar defined by
$$\operatorname{tr}A = {A^i}_i.$$

In general when $p, q \ge 1$, one can define $\operatorname{tr}A$ of a $(p,q)$-tensor $A$ by summing up one upper and one lower indices (depending on which indices to choose, there are many different choices of $\operatorname{tr} A$, one has to by specific). In particular, there isn't a definition of $\operatorname{tr}G$ when $G$ is a $(0,1)$- or $(1,0)$-tensor.

You can understand $G^i G_i$ as (1) First define $G^i$ by $G^i = g^{ij} G_j$, (2) take tensor product B of $(G_i)$ with $(G^j)$, which is a $(1, 1)$-tensor ${B^j}_i = G^jG_i$, and (3) take trace of this $(1, 1)$ tensor: $\operatorname {tr} B = {B^i}_i = G^iG_i$.

Going back to $\nabla^i$, $\nabla_i$: my suggestion is that you treat as if they are just another indices in your tensor: if $A = ({A^{i_1\cdots i_p}}_{j_1\cdots j_q})$ is a $(p,q)$ tensor then $\nabla A$ is a $(p, q+1)$-tensor represented by

$$ \nabla A = (\nabla_i {A^{i_1\cdots i_p}}_{j_1\cdots j_q})$$

So the $i$ in $\nabla_i$ is nothing but a lower index in your new tensor $\nabla A$. Conceptually, raising this index to $\nabla^i A$ is of no difference to raising other $j_k$ for $k=1, \cdots, q$.

To clarify $\nabla^i \nabla_i f$, $\nabla^i f\nabla_i f$ and so on..... First, given a function $f$, one can form the $(0,1)$-tensor $\nabla f = (\nabla_i f)$ and the $(0,2)$-tensor $\nabla \nabla f = (\nabla_j\nabla _i f)$. Then one raise one of the indices of $\nabla \nabla f$ to form a $(1, 1)$ tensor
$$ \nabla^j \nabla_i f := g^{jk}\nabla _k \nabla _i f$$
and we can take trace of this $(1, 1)$-tensor to obtain a scalar
$$\operatorname{tr}(\nabla^j \nabla_i f) = \nabla^i \nabla_i f. $$

On the other hand, $\nabla^i f \nabla_i f$ is quite different: first we have the $(0,1)$-tensor $\nabla f$, then we also obtain $\nabla ^j f$ by raising the index: $\nabla^j  = g^{jk} \nabla_k f$. Next we take tensor product to form a $(1,1)$-form $\nabla^j f \nabla_i f$ and
$$\nabla^i f \nabla_i f = \operatorname{tr} (\nabla^j f\nabla_i f)$$
is the trace of the tensor product.

Similar for $\nabla ^i \nabla_i X$: first we have a $(p, q)$ tensor $X$. Then $\nabla \nabla X$ is a $(p, q+2)$-tensor. Next we raise one of the indice to form a $(p+1, q+1)$-tensor: $\nabla^j \nabla_i X$ (this is an abuse of notation: to be precise we should write $X = {X^{i_1\cdots i_p}}_{j_1\cdots j_q}$ and
$$\tag{1} \nabla^j \nabla_i {X^{i_1\cdots i_p}}_{j_1\cdots j_q}$$
to represent that $(p+1, q+1)$-tensor). Then
$$\nabla^i \nabla_i X$$
is the trace (taking those two upper and lower indice) of the $(p+1, q+1)$-tensor in (1) (so again this is an abuse of notation: we should really write
$$\nabla^i \nabla_i {X^{i_1\cdots i_p}}_{j_1\cdots j_q}.$$
It is also common to use $\nabla^*\nabla X$ to represent the above $(p, q)$-tensor. This is called the rough Laplacian).

Comment: thanks for your notes. that none sense expressions was because of I added last line without thinking. and actually by $G^iG_i=tr G$ I meant $G^i_i=tr G$ and by $G^{ij}G_{jk}=G^i_k$ I meant $G^{ij}_{jk}=G^i_k$.

Comment: @C.F.G I see. So did my answer answer your question (To be honest, like Jackozee Hakkiuz commented above, I don't completely understand your doubt).

Comment: Yes, somewhat. Can you add some computational examples of my last line expressions? $\nabla^i\nabla_i f$ and others.

Comment: @C.F.G I have added something.

Answer (score 1):

Bear in mind that $\nabla^i=g^{ij}\nabla_j$ (or more pedantically, $\nabla^if$ is the unique solution of $Y_i\nabla^if=g^{ij}Y_i\nabla_jf$ for all tangent vectors $Y_i$), where $g^{ij}g_{jk}=\delta^i_k$ relates two metric tensors. So $\nabla^if\nabla_if=g^{ij}\nabla_if\nabla_jf$.